# Object being static

Tags: java, static, inner-classes

I seen this bit of code, Even though I think I got the concept of static in Java I am bit confused. Can any one explain it to me, how an object being static works?

My code:

```
package com.oracle.certification.sampleTest;

public class Person {
    static class Mail {
        static String desc="Male";
    }

    static Gender Mail=new Gender();
}
```

---

```
package com.oracle.certification.sampleTest;

public class Gender {
    String desc="Gender";
}
```

---

```
package com.oracle.certification.sampleTest;

public class Human {
    public static void main(String str[]) {
        System.out.println(Person.Mail.desc);
    }
}
```

When the class Human is run, the O/P is 'gender' not 'male', even though des= gender is nonstatic and des=male is static with static inner class. Also I don't need to import the classes in Hman? I am sorry that I have very little knowledge about inner classes, first of all.

Comment: An object is not `static`. That is not a concept that exists. A variable can be declared `static`.

Comment: Your code is further confused by the use of `Mail` as both a class name and a field name...

Comment: Java Tutorial [Nested Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

Comment: Indeed the question shows that that OP doesn't understand scope rules in Java well, but he posted code that highlights his problem: when he prints `Person.Mail.desc`, it doesn't show `Male` like he expects, but instead it shows `Gender`. That's a far better description of a problem than many that I've seen on SO. Cut the OP some slack please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can any one explain it to me, How an object being static works?

Essentially, `static` in that context means that the entity in question is attached to the class itself, not to an object of the class. Hence, with `static` there is exactly one instance of what you declare:

```
class T {
   public static int staticMember = 0;  // one variable stored in memory
   public int nonStaticMember = 0;      // as many variables stored in memory as objects are created from the class
}
```

See also [What does the 'static' keyword do in a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413898/what-does-the-static-keyword-do-in-a-class)

However, your question is not necessarily a misunderstanding of static classes, but a corner case of name resolution: You are declaring both a type and a member variable with the same name (`Mail`) in one scope (within the `Person` class) - while one might think that this should not even be possible, the Java language does allow this and defines a couple of rules to determine which one to use.

From the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.2):

> A simple name may occur in contexts where it may potentially be interpreted as the **name of a variable, a type**, or a package. In these situations, the rules of §6.5 specify that **a variable will be chosen in preference to a type**.

```
...
static class Mail {   // a Type
}

static Gender Mail ...   // a Variable with the same name 
                         // - the compiler chooses to use this one
...
```

Hence, when referencing `Person.Mail`, the compiler chooses the variable, not the type (the inner class).

Comment: Thanks,  This  was  the  another  concept  that  I  dint  even  think  of.  Thanks  for  letting  me  know.  Now  my  question  is  how  the  object  being  static  works?  I  have  4yrs  of  java  development  experience  but  never  seen  and  object  as  static.

Comment: I  got  it  now.  After  a  long  struggle.  Thanks  all,  especially  @Andreas...